# Odd behavior of radio buttons with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive

I have encountered the following odd behavior when using radio buttons.
What I wanted to accomplish:
If array is undefined - choose Radio Button 1.
When the array is defined, choose Radio Button 2.

Initial state - the array is undefined.

```
function MainCtrl($scope){
  $scope.model = {}; };
```

The behavior i've encountered:

- If I use ng-model + value + ng-checked on both radio buttons -
  everything works as expected. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34dT9/
- If i use ng-checked + NO ng-model + NO value - everything works as
  expected.
- However, if i use ng-model + ng-checked + NO value - NONE of the
  radio buttons are select, despite the condition for radio button
  being evaluated to TRUE. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34dT9/1/

My assumption is that the behavior due to the fact that AngularJS documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) seems to state that the element must have ng-model and value set, but ng-change is optional. However, one of the test cases above, shows that using just ng-change (without the seemingly mandatory attributes/directives) produces the desired behavior.

I am having hard time understanding this behavior and will be glad someone will be able to explain it to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late.

I have changed the condition from

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="model.permissions"  name="fooradio" ng-checked="model.permissions == null"> Radio 1
<input type="radio" ng-model="model.permissions" name="fooradio" ng-checked="model.permissions != null"> Radio 2
```

to

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="model.permissions"  name="fooradio" ng-checked="model.permissions === null"> Radio 1
 <input type="radio" ng-model="model.permissions" name="fooradio" ng-checked="model.permissions !== null"> Radio 2
```

I am checking the value strictly here with (=== & !==) which will check the type as well.

Please find the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varit05/44ugfea8/) for third scenario.